# How to easily import data when migrating to a newer version of magento?

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I am maintaining a magento shop and its sort of messy now with age. Also want to implement a fresh design. Current version is 1.7.0.2. I am thinking of making a fresh install and build a new theme to leave behind all the mess (many programmers have worked on it). I came across this blog - http://www.2hatslogic.com/blog/importing-data-to-new-version-install-of-magento-cleanup-easy . If it works as said in the article, that would be exactly what I want. Do you think its possible as in the blog article?

I know that the DB changes with the newer versions for the imported DB tables might not be carried over since the core_resource table have updated version number for each modules, but if I copy this table as well, then Magneto should update all tables with the set up SQL and it should all be fine I assume?

Thanks in advance!
Aneesh

Comment: @annesh: it's not possible straight forward as described in blog.
blog is described based on default Magento.
you will lose data like points, used coupons and many other 3rd party extension data.
best way is to upgrade database with default Magento newer version.
and then step by step move all 3rd party extensions and your changes

Comment: Ok, thank you. In my case the site don't have many plugins or they haven't set up any coupon codes or anything. Then the only thing that needs copying is the shipping rules and tax rules I assume. Of course updating payment and shipping methods credentials. Then this could work?

Comment: yes it should work, but if you have customized any of the sales table, you need to move all customization too not the data only. Also when you copy data, don't set SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0; best of luck